# perl - comparing two strings, one a subroutine parameter

Tags: perl

I am trying to work through what should be some simple exercises and with this one I am having problem comparing two strings (one in an array, and the other as supplied to a function). In particular, the line:

```
 if ($el eq $iName)
```

doesn't return 1 even when the two strings are equal.

I have put some debug lines above that piece of code to see what is the value of that boolean and it seems as though it is undef.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use v5.14.0;


sub greet {
    #early example - no hashes, 

    #if first ever name print the name, 
    #if not first and not previously seen, print previous names, 
    #if same name as one previous, acknowledge this and print previous names

    my $iName = $_[0];
    state @seen_names;

    if (!@seen_names) {
        print "Hello $iName\n";
        push @seen_names, "$iName ";
    } else {
        my $push_name = 0;
        foreach my $el (@seen_names) {

#------------------------DEBUG-----------
        print "equal? ", ("$el" eq "$iName"), "----\n"; #debug - the boolean looks undef
        print "equal? ", ("$el" eq undef), "----\n"; #debug
        print "equal? ", ("a" eq "a"), "----\n"; #debug
#------------------------DEBUG-----------

            if ($el eq $iName) { #debug - do not get into this if
                #FIXME prints *all* names, including this one.
                print "hello again $iName, all visitors so far: " , @seen_names, "\n";
            } else {
                print "hello $iName, all visitors so far: @seen_names.\n";
                $push_name = 1;
            }
        }
        if ($push_name) {
            push @seen_names, "$iName ";
        }
    }
}

&greet ("Greg");
&greet ("Greg");
#&greet ("Bob");
#&greet ("James");
#&greet ("Jill");
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I've edited your question to fix the ne/ eq issue. I'll remove my "answer" now :-)

Comment: Why do you push "$iName " instead of simply $iName?

Comment: I might be misinterpreting your question here but every time I see a name that hasn't yet been encountered I add it to the @seen_names array (after looping), which saves its state between function calls. If the name has already been seen, the variable $push_name stays false and the supplied name does not get pushed into the array again.

Comment: Thing I don't understand is why you push "$iName " (that is content of $iName plus extra space) but you compare $el to "$iName" or $iName, without extra space.

Comment: Of course!!! that was so that I could just print the array without another loop and all the names being "stuck together"; but that means the if will always evaluate false! (which now I've tested it doesn't print a zero if I did print ("b" eq "a")). Thanks!

Comment: @sawyer Consider making that an answer! @HexedAgain If you directly interpolate an array into a string, e.g. `say "visitors: @seen_names"`, then the elements are joined with a space in between. You can also use the `join` function: `join ", ", @seen_names`.

Comment: thanks for that, looking back through the book, prior to the exercise I was working on I noticed that it mentions interpolating array elements in a string, and so I went with that - further, after resolving that bit I noticed that I was printing something for every iteration of the loop! (fixed now). I don't think I have come across join yet so that may be useful in future exercises.

Further, I agree that sawyer's response serves very well as an answer.

Comment: Suggest you post your own solution as an answer :-)

Comment: @HexedAgain Please do not add "solved" to your question title. If you figured out a solution of your own, please post it as an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) by clicking the check mark in the left margin.

Comment: @Amal Murali, that's fair enough, answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is in resolving the following error, that is, I am populating @seen_names via:

```
push @seen_names, "$iName ";
```

yet the $iName in

```
if ($el eq $iName)
```

does not have a space in it; hence the if will always fail.